# Displaying nested JSON using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, client, livesearch

I currently have a live search box that displays json. However I am having issues in working out how to display the nested JSON.

I am looking to display the images and the "closed" days. Any help would be appreciated. I have include my java-script and a sample of my json.

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {

var searchTerm = $(this).val();
var myExp = new RegExp(searchTerm, "i");

$.get("shops.php",function(data,status){

var response='';
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
shops = json.shops;

    $.each(shops, function(index, item) {
        if(item.shop_name.search(myExp) != -1){
        response += "<h2>"+item.shop_name+"</h2>"; 
    response += "<h2>"+item.distance_citycentre.driving_miles+"</h2>"; 

});

} 

$("#content").html(response);

});
});
```

Here is a sample of my JSON.

```
{"shops": [
{ "shop_name":"tesco",
"distance_citycentre": {
"driving_miles":"1.5",
"driving_minutes":"3"
}, 
"closed": [
"monday",
"wedensday",
"friday"
],
"images" [
{
"description":"lake",
"id":"1"
},
{
"description":"ocean",
"id":"2"
}
]
}, 
{"shop_name":"asda", etc.......
```

Comment: If you're talking about how to access json objects in an array which is in an array, you can access them by using array[0].object.array[0].object.array[0].array[0]

Comment: Check if your json output is correct, because i found error in json code near "image" error it requires colon-":"

Answer (score 1):

Here goes your solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var data = '{ "shops":[{"closed":["monday","wedensday","friday"],"images" :[{"description":"lake","id":"1"},{"description":"ocean","id":"2"}]}]}';

var response='';
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
shops = json.shops;

alert(shops[0].closed[0] + " - "+shops[0].closed[1] + " - " +shops[0].closed[2]);

alert(shops[0].images[0].description + " - "+shops[0].images[0].id);


});
```

And change the JSON Output if possible, There is a little error near "image"<<-- It requires colon **":"** You can find the same working model on [JSfiddle][1]

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/u6exgn7s/ here

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about how to access json objects in an array which is in an array, you can access them by using `array[0].object.array[0].object.array[0].array[0]`

In your example you can select closed day 'monday' by using:

```
item.shops[0].closed[0];
```

or friday by using:

```
item.shops[0].closed[2];
```

You determine the position in the array by [-number from 0 to infinity-]